# Expected declaration specifier error in function

Tags: c

New to the exchange so sorry if my formatting is off.
I am getting an error for "expected declaration specifiers" This is in the is_prime function I have defined at the bottom. Can you shed some light on this error and how to correct it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    int n;
    int k;
    int j;

//gets user input for length of string
    printf("Enter the value of n:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
//stores user input as n

    printf("Printing primes less than or equal to %d: \n", n);

    for(k = 2; k <= n; k++)
    {
        if(is_Prime(k) == 1)
        {
            printf("%d,", k);
        }
    }


   //here is the is_Prime function
{
int is_Prime (int k)


for(j = 2; j < k; j++)
    {
if(k%j != 0)
      {
    return 1;
      }

else if(k%j == 0)
       {
return 0;
break;
       }
    }   
}
```

here are the output errors

```
main.c: In function 'is_Prime':                                                                                                                                                 
main.c:29:1: error: expected declaration specifiers before 'for'                                                                                                                
 for(j = 2; j < k; j++)                                                                                                                                                         
 ^                                                                                                                                                                              
main.c:29:12: error: expected declaration specifiers before 'j'                                                                                                                 
 for(j = 2; j < k; j++)                                                                                                                                                         
            ^                                                                                                                                                                   
main.c:29:19: error: expected declaration specifiers before 'j'                                                                                                                 
 for(j = 2; j < k; j++)                                                                                                                                                         
                   ^                                                                                                                                                            
main.c:42:1: error: expected declaration specifiers before '}' token                                                                                                            
 }                                                                                                                                                                              
 ^                                                                                                                                                                              
main.c:42:1: error: expected '{' at end of input                                                                                                                                
main.c: In function 'main':                                                                                                                                                     
main.c:42:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

Comment: It's no use apologising about the formatting. If you had done so, you would have immediately seen where the missing closing, and opening braces are. Formatting isn't just to make the code "look nice", it's truly essential. Down voted.

Comment: I was apologizing about the formatting of my question not the code. I know most forums have a general way they expect a question to be asked.

Comment: Also, why do you have "else(k%j == 0)"?  Did you intend to have 'else if'?  You need to declare "int j" inside the function.  The break in the else block is superfluous (as is the for loop, as written), since it will always return from either the if or the else.

Comment: i have the break to stop is_prime function from executing further because k is not prime if that condition is met.

Comment: Try indenting your code properly, then the brace mismatch will be more apparent.

Comment: I agree that the question does present issues that could've been prevented by careful coding and the issues could've been discovered through taking time to better understand basic C structure. The typical advice to down-voted items is to edit the post. However, the comments suggest that the post should never have been asked. On the other hand, the comments/answers combined with the original question shed light on yet another cryptic gcc compiler error. If the OP or I were to edit the original posting, the meaning would be lost. What to do? (I guess this is a meta comment...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `is_Prime` inside the body of `main`. This is not possible in C.

Or alternately, you are missing a closing curly brace at the end of `main`'s body.

The other problem was already mentioned in [shf301's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28799279/908515).

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the opening curly brace `{` for the `is_Prime` function.